# Socket Communication between Server (C Program) and Client (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, sockets, jsocket

I'm trying to establish a socket communication between a server( C program ) and a client( JavaScript ) and display the messages on Web browser. TCP/IP Protocol is employed to achieve this. I'm successfully able to up the server, but struggling with the Javascript since it is new to me.

I've tried using `jSocket()` but the `jSocket.onReady()` function doesn't seem to trigger. I'm stuck. Can anyone please share a working code of Javascript which can connect to a server and exchange the messages back and forth.